# Error while indexing .xml files in solr

Tags: solr, solr-cell

I am trying to index xml files in solr search engine using following command:

```
java -Durl=http://10.1.11.143:8080/solr/#/ -jar post.jar solr.xml
```

But I am getting following error:

```
SimplePostTool version 1.5
Posting files to base url http://10.1.11.143:8080/solr/#/ using content-type application/xml..
POSTing file solr.xml
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #500 Internal Server Error
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException:    Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://10.1.11.143:8080/solr/#/
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://10.1.11.143:8080/solr/#/..
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #500 Internal Server Error for url http://10.1.11.143:8080/solr/#/?commit=true
Time spent: 0:00:00.017
```

Please help me to come out of this error.
Content of solr.xml is as shown in the picture:
[image]

Comment: Can you post the structure of solr.xml with some data

Comment: @buddy86 please find the content of solr.xml in the attached picture.

Comment: Solr.xml is already existing file in exampledocs directory

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because of the URL. You didn't mention any requestHandler while updating. Use the following command. It'll work.

`java -Durl=http://10.1.11.143:8080/solr/update?commit=true -jar post.jar solr.xml`

`/update` is the requestHandler to index data into Solr.

Comment: But I tried the same command and I was able to post solr.xml file. Please check if the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Now I have made some changes in permissions and moved missing folders and I am getting error:                           "SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #405 Method Not Allowed"